# how to do speech recognition for windows power-point

Tags: c#, powerpoint, speech-recognition

I am undergraduate student and my third year computer mini project is the artificial intelligence. I am going to control windows power-point presentation using voice commands so here is the things i want.

windows power point slideshow should be in full screen when i say **"full screen"**  and it should go to next slide when i say **"next"**.. when i say **"back"** previous slide should be displayed. only these thing i want but  I can't use windows speech recognition system in my project. so can anyone help me. i am using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google for C# speech recognition library, you will find:

[C# Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906778/c-sharp-speech-recognition)
and
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a

Once you are able to recognize speech, you can issue controls to PowerPoint. If you google "controlling PowerPoint programmatically", you will find
[Controlling PowerPoint Slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994892/controlling-powerpoint-slideshow)

Those two things should get you going.